# LINQ group items into lists in anonymous type, with duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 boxes that can contain fruit:

> A - apples, oranges, pears
>
> B - apples, bananas
>
> C - pears

I'd like to create a LINQ query statement that generates a new anonymous type that groups the boxes by the fruit they contain (not actual code):

```
fruitBoxes.apples = {A, B}
fruitBoxes.oranges = {A}
fruitBoxes.bananas = {B}
fruitBoxes.pears = {A, C}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All anonymous type properties have to be known at compile time, so unless you know exactly what fruits you're going to deal with (which is unlikely) you can't use anonymous types.

You can use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead:

```
var result = boxes.SelectMany(b => b.Fruits.Select(f => new { Box = b, Fruit = f }))
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Fruit, x => x.Box.Name)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

`Box` is defined as:

```
class Box
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Fruits { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var boxes = new []
{
    new { box = "A", fruit = new [] { "apples", "oranges", "pears", }, },
    new { box = "B", fruit = new [] { "apples", "bananas", }, },
    new { box = "C", fruit = new [] { "pears", }, },
};

var query =
    from b in boxes
    from f in b.fruit
    group b.box by f into bs
    select new
    {
        fruit = bs.Key,
        boxes = bs.ToArray(),
    };
```

The result I get it this:

[image: result]